# Local linear trend model versus ARIMA

Tags: arima, state-space-models

I was told that the local linear trend model also called 'basic structural model':

$\mu_t=\mu_{t-1}+\beta_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$

$\beta_t=\beta_{t-1}+\xi_t$

Is 'equivalent' to an ARIMA(0,1,1)

That's not obvious to me, Can anyone give me some references on the equivalence between structural time  series models and arima models ?

Comment: Welcome to CV. See chap 2 of the classical [book by A.C. Harvey](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/forecasting-structural-time-series-models-and-the-kalman-filter/CE5E112570A56960601760E786A5E631). As such, the *basic structural model* involves a seasonal component.

Comment: Thanks @Yves ! I think at found it, surprisingly it says that it is ARIMA(0,2,2) in stead of ARIMA(0,1,1) , it becomes (0,1,1) only if the level is deterministic but I will study this in detail, thanks !  If you change it into an answer then I can give you some points I think ?

Comment: Thank you. Yes ARIMA(0,1,1)  is for the *local level* model.

Comment: @Yves:  the local linear trend model and ARIMA(0,2,2) seem to be 'equivalent', but that doesn't necessarily imply that their estimation is as efficient, e.g. if I estimate the ARIMA coefficients with maximum likelihood and the linear trend model with the KALMAN filter, then I would say that the Kalman filter might take recent 'breaks' (like covid) better into account ?

Comment: Mind the difference between the model and the algorithm(s). The KF is most often used to compute predictons from ARIMA models and to estimate these, once put in state space form (see the code in the R stats package). Most structural time series models are ARIMA with possibliy some inequality constraints on the coefficients  (p. 56 in my edition of the book). I do not believe that these constraints would make a difference in the case you cite.